# Python - Extracting values from a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list as shown below:

```
[{'id': 'id_123',
  'type': 'type_1',
  'created_at': '2020-02-12T17:45:00Z'},
 {'id': 'id_124',
  'type': 'type_2',
  'created_at': '2020-02-12T18:15:00Z'},
 {'id': 'id_125',
  'type': 'type_1',
  'created_at': '2020-02-13T19:43:00Z'},
 {'id': 'id_126',
  'type': 'type_3',
  'created_at': '2020-02-13T07:00:00Z'}]
```

I am trying to find how many times `type : type_1` occurs and what is the earliest `created_at` timestamp in that list for `type_1`

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this in several steps.

To find the number of times `type_1` occurs we can use the built-in [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) in tandem with [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

```
from operator import itemgetter

def my_filter(item):
    return item['type'] == 'type_1'

key = itemgetter('created_at')

items = sorted(filter(my_filter, data), key=key)
print(f"Num records is {len(items)}")
print(f"Earliest record is {key(items[0])}")

Num records is 2
Earliest record is 2020-02-12T17:45:00Z
```

Conversely you can use a generator-comprehension and then sort the generator.

```
gen = (item for item in data if item['type'] == 'type_1')
items = sorted(gen, key=key)
# rest of the steps are the same...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension to get all the sublists you're interested in, then sort by 'created_at'.

```
l = [{'id': 'id_123',
  'type': 'type_1',
  'created_at': '2020-02-12T17:45:00Z'},
 {'id': 'id_124',
  'type': 'type_2',
  'created_at': '2020-02-12T18:15:00Z'},
 {'id': 'id_125',
  'type': 'type_1',
  'created_at': '2020-02-13T19:43:00Z'},
 {'id': 'id_126',
  'type': 'type_3',
  'created_at': '2020-02-13T07:00:00Z'}]

ll = [x for x in l if x['type'] == 'type_1']
ll.sort(key=lambda k: k['created_at'])
print(len(ll))
print(ll[0]['created_at'])
```

Output:

```
2
02/12/2020 17:45:00
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `filter` and `min`.

**Ex:**

```
data = [{'id': 'id_123',
  'type': 'type_1',
  'created_at': '2020-02-12T17:45:00Z'},
 {'id': 'id_124',
  'type': 'type_2',
  'created_at': '2020-02-12T18:15:00Z'},
 {'id': 'id_125',
  'type': 'type_1',
  'created_at': '2020-02-13T19:43:00Z'},
 {'id': 'id_126',
  'type': 'type_3',
  'created_at': '2020-02-13T07:00:00Z'}]

onlytype_1 = list(filter(lambda x: x['type'] == 'type_1', data))
print(len(onlytype_1))
print(min(onlytype_1, key=lambda x: x['created_at']))
```

Or:

```
temp = {}
for i in data:
    temp.setdefault(i['type'], []).append(i)

print(len(temp['type_1']))
print(min(temp['type_1'], key=lambda x: x['created_at']))
```

**Output:**

```
2
{'id': 'id_123', 'type': 'type_1', 'created_at': '2020-02-12T17:45:00Z'}
```

Comment: You have nice answers for the most part, but this constant use of `list(filter(...))` and `list(map(...))` with `lambda` is doing my head in. In those cases, a list comprehension is usually shorter, always more readable, and just as Pythonic, if not more =)

Answer (score 0):

You can just generate a list of all the type_1s using a `list_comprehension`, and them use `sort` with `datetime.strptime` to sort the values accordingly

```
from datetime import datetime

# Generate a list with only the type_1s' created_at values
type1s = [val['created_at'] for val in vals if val['type']=="type_1"]

# Sort them based on the timestamps
type1s.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))

# Print the lowest value
print(type1s[0])

#'2020-02-12T17:45:00Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to get the desired output:

```
from datetime import datetime

def sol(l):
    sum_=0
    dict_={}

    for x in l:
        if x['type']=='type_1':
            sum_+=1
            dict_[x['id']]=datetime.strptime(x['created_at'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

    date =sorted(dict_.values())[0]
    for key,value in dict_.items():
        if value== date: id_=key
    return sum_,date,id_

sol(l)
```

This function gives the number of times type ='type_1', corresponding minimum date and its id respectively.

Hope this helps!